# PHP generating html

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP, coming from ASP.net background, the most trouble I am having is generating html from PHP. My question is how is it done in industry? I see 4 ways:

1. generate from inside PHP program.
2. use PHP "helper classes" to do that.
3. mix PHP from inside HTML.
4. use templates.

Are there more ways, and which one is used on professional projects. If it number 2 or 4, could you suggest "best" (most used) helper classes, or templates.

Comment: It depends. It always depends. In ASP.NET, you have roughly the same options - code-behind and templates, MVC, mixing code in with `<% %>` tags...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an MVC framework like [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.org), and follow the standards there. Try to keep your business and display logic as separate as possible!

The reasoning behind this is that if you decide later on to modify your code, it's easier to find the code in question. It's simpler to search through a few template files than it is to pick through all your logic to look for one snippet of html.

Comment: @minitech The microediting isn't really necessary for one character, and since "CodeIgniter" is a portmanteau of the two words and the extra space didn't detract from the meaning...

Comment: Correcting the error in thissentence wouldn't detract from its meaning, but it's still as annoying as when people call jQuery Jquery.

Comment: I'm not particularly bothered by a small error here or there, it's all semantics anyway. However, the change in link syntax bothers me. Y u no liek html? :(

Answer (score 0):

Most professional development is now done using an MVC framework, such as CakePHP or CodeIgniter.

You could also look at a standalone templating system like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Answer (score 0):

When you start with php, you find several ways to generate your webpages.

Html is a template language, so it is just formatted string, and php is very good generating string, so you have a lot of ways to do it.

But some ways are better than others.

For example: If you mix your html code with your php code, you get a very difficut to read, mantain and scale code, so it is better if you separate the code in layers. MVC is a design pattern that handles very good this kind of layer abstraction, so read a little about it.

Inside PHP, you could find several tools to do it at the good way, like using a framework for your project. The frameworks make easy and quick your development and manage the mvc abstraction well.
I recommend Laravel, it is easy to use and is so powerful, that you will do your job really fast.

But if you don't want to use a framework, you still could separate your logic from the html code, and fill the html only whe you need. Look at [The following class](https://gist.github.com/judasane/6552314), maybe it could be useful to you.